# Q: Error while testing Tensorflow Object Detection Training

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am getting following error while running object_detection/train.py, Do I have to specify the regularizer in the pipeline config file ?

File "/Users/test/Desktop/models-master/object_detection/builders/hyperparams_builder.py", line 117, in _build_regularizer

raise ValueError('Unknown regularizer function: {}'.format(regularizer_oneof))

ValueError: Unknown regularizer function: None

Comment: Can you link to your config file?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan , After adding the fields in "model" config section in the pipeline config file using the info from a forum post , the error went away but I could not find any documentation about the how to populate the "model" section in pipeline config file similar to train_config  section. Do you know where I can find this info?